# Fastest way to insert millions of rows with an increment in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, integer

I have a table with ONE bigint-field. Now I would like to insert millions of rows with an increment so I came up with this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertMe()
BEGIN
 DECLARE i BIGINT DEFAULT 1;
 WHILE (i <= 999999999) DO  
   INSERT INTO mytable values(i);  
   SET i=i+1;
 END WHILE;
END;
```

Of course this beast takes way too long, so normally I would do the following:

```
INSERT INTO mytable values(1),(2),(3) etc
```

But how do I create the String then and wouldn't that take too long as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field. If you attempt to insert a `NULL` in that field, MySQL generates the auto number for you so there is no need to build the (1), (2), ... string. Give this a try:

```
CREATE TABLE seed(column1 BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=MyISAM;

-- INSERT ONE ROW TO BEGIN WITH
INSERT INTO seed(column1) VALUES(NULL);

-- RUN THIS QUERY 20 TIMES TO GENERATE 1,048,576 ROWS
INSERT INTO seed(column1)
SELECT NULL
FROM seed;
```

20 iterations of the above queries on a MyISAM table took ~4.5 seconds.

Comment: Every time one calls the above there is a gap between insertions and the more often you call it the higher the gap e.g 1,2,3,4,6 and then 7,8,9,13 and then 18,19,20,28 and so on and so on

Comment: During bulk inserts, InnoDB generates auto_increment values that may contain gaps. It is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html). The workaround requires you to change MySQL configuration which is not a viable option, so I suggest that you begin with a MyISAM table and convert it to InnoDB after populating it with data.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in a transaction, this will have the same effect.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertMe()
BEGIN
 DECLARE i BIGINT DEFAULT 1;
 START TRANSACTIOON;
 WHILE (i <= 999999999) DO
   INSERT INTO mytable values(i);  
   SET i=i+1;
 END WHILE;
 COMMIT;
END;
```